# Data Masking in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, masking, data-masking

I'm trying to mask all other ID's when a specific ID is selected. But it will not run. This is what I have so far.

This is my current code:

```
USE [DB1]
Declare IDCursor Cursor
    For
        Select ID, Year, Amount, RefreshDate 
        From Table1
        For Update
    Open IDCursor
    Declare @ID int, @Year datetime, @Amount money, @RefreshDate datetime
    Fetch Next From IDCursor 
    Into @ID, @Year, @Amount, @RefreshDate 
    While @@Fetch_Status = 0
Begin
    If @ID <> 0
    SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 0, 5)

    Else
    Set @ID = 0

End
Close IDCursor 
Deallocate IDCursor
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: nothing shows, it just constantly runs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is just a typo?  Did you want to do the below set @ID differently?

```
Begin
    If @ID <> 0
    Set @ID = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 0, 5)
   --OR MAYBE SELECT @ID = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 0, 5)

Else
    Set @ID = 0
```

End

Comment: it just keeps saying 'executing query'. it's been running for almost an hour already

Comment: Cursors are the way I generally steer clear of.  Can you not do the    update as part of a set based, i.e. 
        update
     Table1
    set
     ID = Case
      when ID = 0 THEN 0
      else SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 0, 5)
     end

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition `While @@Fetch_Status = 0` never changes so you have an infinite loop.  You need to keep fetching inside the loop:

```
While @@Fetch_Status = 0
Begin
    ...
    Fetch Next From IDCursor Into @ID, @Year, @Amount, @RefreshDate 
End
```